How to create a SSBO with dynamic size
I have looked everywhere but couldn't find one that used DSA (Direct State Access). I need a SSBO with dynamic size so that I can update my instances WITHOUT having a limit like MAX_INSTANCE_COUNT.
At the moment what I do is:
size_t datasize = 0;
void* data = nullptr;
unsigned int index = 0;

unsigned int id = 0;
glCreateBuffers(1, &id);
glNamedBufferStorage(id, datasize, data, GL_DYNAMIC_STORAGE_BIT);
glBindBufferRange(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, index, id, 0, datasize);

Then in the loop what I do is:
glNamedBufferData(id, (GLsizeiptr)datasize, data, GL_STREAM_DRAW);

I did use "glNamedBufferSubData" but that doesn't really let me go above the datasize.
If you could explain step by step how I could do this, I'd really appreciate it.

but couldn't find one that used DSA -- Please spell out in words what "DSA" means.

@PaulMcKenzie "Direct State Access" modified the question to spell it out.

@Fareanor oh no, I don't need to preallocate memory, I just need a way to dynamically allocate memory so that the size can be changing.

@Alphenex Oops sorry I misunderstood what SSBO meant (I confused it with SBO -> Small buffer optimization)... I removed my comment

As you are finding out with this question, acronyms are evil. Never use one until AFTER you spell it out.  Even then , in a long enough document, expect people to forget or skip past the definition and misinterpret what you've written.

OpenGL doesn't have a concept of "dynamic storage". You can use BufferData to allocate new storage for them, but you really shouldn't. It's best to preallocate storage and if you blow past that limit, either generate an error or allocate a new buffer entirely.
Also, you cannot call BufferData on a buffer with immutable storage (which your call to BufferStorage created). The whole point of immutable storage buffers is that you can't reallocate them.

Oh this is somewhat the answer I am looking for. So I should be using BufferData instead of BufferStorage to allocate a specific size and then if the limit is exceeded just recreate the SSBO with a larger limit (such as double the previous limit)?

@Alphenex: No, you should use buffer storage and make sure the limit is not exceeded. If it is exceeded, make a new buffer object and copy the contents over.
